# iPad conditional CSS isnt working

Tags: css, ipad, conditional-statements, media-queries

I've read several of the questions on here as well as Google looking for stuff and I found a lot bu tfor some reason I can't get mine to work for iPads. I was able to get it working for iPhones but the iPad is still displaying my bg img. These are all the queries I've tried and came up empty handed.

```
    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {

body.custom-background {

    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    background-image: none;

}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 1024px) {

body.custom-background {

    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    background-image: none;

}
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {

body.custom-background {

    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    background-image: none;

}
}

@media handheld and (max-device-width: 480px) {

body.custom-background {

    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    background-image: none;

}
}
```

Comment: The third media query is the right one. The fourth doesn't make sense for an iPad. Can we see your HTML?

Comment: The fourth query is for iPhone. Sorry I didnt specify that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May you have `Meta` in you html head. like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

with that media query

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {

body.custom-background {

    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    background-image: none;

}
}
```

Comment: Well I looked in the index.php file and the linked handheld.css was only set to media type handheld so I set it to handheld, screen. After changing that iphone and ipad both worked fine and didnt show background image but then when viewed on a desktop it also didnt show the image. handheld.css now only has queries three and four in it.