# Choosing a specific stylesheet on a wordpress site when showing the site in a tab

Tags: css, facebook, tabs

This might be an easy question (hopefully) for you to answer. Not sure this is the right place to post the question, since I do not know if this is a CSS issue or a normal PHP programming issue (I know very little about PHP programming), so here goes:

I have a wordpress blog that uses three different stylesheets depending on the platform where the blog is viewed (web, ipad, iphone).

I recently made a tab on my Facebook page which opens the blog in an iframe, but it opens the web-style (default) stylesheet which is way too wide for the max width in Facebook tabs (810 px). However, the ipad-adapted stylesheet would work just fine there. I still wish to see the normal web-style view when I enter my web from outside Facebook, so it isn't an option to swith to the ipad-stylesheet as a default stylesheet.

Is there a way of passing on a parameter from the facebook tab: e.g. http://www.myblog.com/?style=facebook so that the site that shows inside the facebook tab uses the right stylesheet? I would think more people have had this problem but I have scoured the Internet for hours without knowing really what to look for. Somebody spoke about CSS selectors, but I have no clue as to how they work or how to implement them in a solution.

This is the code in the header.php that deals with the stylesheets:

```
<!-- Theme Styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<?php $disable_theme_features = of_get_option( 'disable_theme_features' ); if ($disable_theme_features['4'] == '0') { ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/style-ipad.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<?php } if ($disable_theme_features['3'] == '0') { ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/style-iphone.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<?php } ?>
```

Is there a way to make this happening without resorting to a complete makeover of the template? Any help would be greatly appreciated!! And sorry again if this is a noob question, that is because i am noob at PHP.

Thanks again!

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9188127/ipad-conditional-css-isnt-working

Answer (score 0):

You could use a PHP if statement. Such as if at the URL, then use this stylesheet.